# Failing to Debug Kotlin Tomcat web app with IntelliJ and docker

Tags: spring, docker, debugging, tomcat, kotlin

I'm attempting to remote debug a simple Kotlin based tomcat web app with Spring Boot that's relying on docker container with IntelliJ.

The app code is -

```
package com.microservices.MyApp

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@SpringBootApplication
class MyAppApplication

@RestController
class GreetingsController
{
    @GetMapping("/")
    fun greetings() = "hello from Docker"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>)
{
    runApplication<MyAppApplication>(*args)
}
```

I add a breakpoint on

```
fun greetings() = "hello from Docker"
```

Just as a simple test. When I run the app locally (not via docker) break point works fine when I go to localhost:8080

Now, to get it working with docker I created a docker file -

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/*.jar microservice.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "microservice.jar"]
```

I have a simple docker edit config, that when I run I provide "-d -p8080:8080" as an argument. I again hit localhost:8080 and it works fine.

Now, to debug that, I create a Remote edit config, set "Launch docker before debug" with the docker configuration I provided above, set the port to 5005. I run the remote config, launches fine, I hit localhost:8080 - works fine.

So i'm getting the output I want. However, when I set a breakpoint on the greetings() function - unlike when I'm running the app locally (that is not with docker container) it FAILS to trigger the breakpoint.

I have tried different ports for the remote config (8000) and nothing. I tried exposing different ports in the docker config and nothing. I simplye CANNOT get that breakpoint to get triggered when I'm running a remote debug session with Docker, but do manage to easily trigger it when I'm running the app locally.

Anyone have any insight what could be going on? I'm using IntelliJ Community 2019.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 4 days I figured out what's going on. I'm placing this here so anyone else can know if they hit the same issue.

You need to add this to your dockerfile

ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n

Then create a docker configuration with the following run options

-d -p8080:8080 -p8000:8000

Create a remote configuration with the port 8000

Place breakpoints BEFORE kick-starting any debugging sessions - it won't get picked at run-time

Then whenever you wish to debug your Dockerized Kotlin Spring Boot Tom Cat app (say that 3 times fast), launch the docker config first THEN launch the debug remote attaching to it.

And that'll be that.